# Objetos estáticos em Activities com View Pagers

Tags: android, android-fragment, static, android-context, android-recyclerview

Tenho uma activity com um view pager, e este controla 3 fragmentos, f1, f2, f3. O fragmento f1 mostra itens adicionados pelo usuário, o fragmento f2 carrega todos os itens de um servidor externo, mostrando-os numa lista, e por fim, o fragmento f3 mostra os itens que o usuário decidiu guardar. Os itens guardados pelo usuário, são salvos em txt, logo, não precisam de acesso ao servidor.

**O problema**: Sempre que o usuário guardar um item, eu preciso adicionar uma marcação no item selecionado em f2, e automaticamente o adicionar em f3, e o mesmo acontece quando o usuário desmarca em f3 e o item precisa ser atualizado em f2, mas nesse caso apenas o layout, já que não tem a ver com conexões externas.

**A solução criada por mim**: Deixar os adaptadores públicos e estáticos na activity e criar métodos dentro dela que atualize os adaptadores sempre que houver uma ação, pra isso, tive que criar uma classe que extends a classe `Application`, para criar um contexto global.

**A dúvida**: Sabe-se que não é bom criar contextos estáticos por problemas de vazamento de memória, mas creio que isso deve acontecer pois manter código funcionando durante outras activities, realmente deve pesar. Mas usar essa solução entre fragmentos, já que estes estão sempre funcionando em primeiro plano, também pode trazer riscos de vazamento de memória? Observando que eu apenas uso o contexto estático nessa activity para que possa ser atualizado os adaptadores por outros fragmentos.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Não há a possibilidade de se criar um singleton para comportar os adaptadores/dados? Dessa forma, nao é necessário mexer com contexto e com a application. Tem uma lib chamada eventbus, que serve para esse tipo de problema. Ela envia uma mensagem para "o nada" e um determinado método vai ficar "ouvindo" se essa mensagem foi chamada.

http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/

Comment: Parece ser interessante essa ideia. Mas eu conseguiria implementar isso mesmo que meus adaptadores precisem de parâmetros do tipo contexto?

Comment: Não entendi o problema. pode especificar mais?

Comment: Os adaptadores que estou usando necessitam do parâmetro Context, e a minha dúvida, é se usando o EventBus, o contexto pode ser usado nessa biblioteca? Ele não acabaria sendo estático também?

Comment: creio que não. variáveis normais dentro de métodos estáticos continuam sendo variáveis normais. então, creio que não vai mudar nada.

Answer (score 0):

Existe algumas maneiras de resolver este seu problema., Uma alternativa:

#### Criar uma interface

```
public interface MeuFragmentInterface {
    void fragmentBecameVisible();
}
```

#### Anexar ouvidor no setOnPageChangeListene

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float v, final int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
            MeuFragmentInterface fragment = (MeuFragmentInterface) mPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, position);
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.fragmentBecameVisible();
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int position) {
        }
    });
```

#### Implementar Interface no seu Fragment

```
public class MinhaActivity extends Fragment implements MeuFragmentInterface{
    @Override
    public void fragmentBecameVisible() {
          System.out.println("TestFragment");
    }
}
```

Assim você pode chamar seu método durante a ação do `fragment`.

#### Detalhes

- [Fragments onResume from back stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503189/fragments-onresume-from-back-stack)
- [Fragment onResume() & onPause() is not called on backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326155/fragment-onresume-onpause-is-not-called-on-backstack)

Comment: Certo, isso faz sentido, mas eu gostaria de atualizar os itens dos adaptadores assim que o clique é executado, não apenas quando ele é visível para o usuário. Penso nisso, para que o usuário não veja a animação de adicionar ou remover itens dos recyclers... compreende?